# Get access to a Global.asax property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api application with C# and .NET Framework.

My question is very easy. This is my `Global.asax` class.

**Global.asax:**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public MyClass MyClassVM
    {
        get { return Singleton.MyClassVM; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

And I want to get access to `MyClassVM` on my `ApiController`. How can I do that?

Comment: @mason Maybe this is the first time I work with ASP.NET MVC Web Api. If you have a better approach, please share it with us.

Comment: @mason I did that because it is the first I do something like that and I don't know how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason that you are introducing an indirection here? If  not, I do not see why you cannot use the singleton *directly* from your controller like so:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    Singleton.MyClassVM...
}
```

Otherwise could you not make the `MyClassVM` property `static` and then access it via the type from the controller?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to use Singleton directly from my ApiController, where do I have to put it? I mean, on which folder? App_Start?

Comment: Shouldn't matter which directory it is in so long as it is `public` or `internal`.

Comment: @VansFannel Try accessing the `Singleton.MyClassVM` from the controllers' action method and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you please explain this: "Otherwise could you not make the MyClassVM property static and then access it via the type from the controller?"? Thanks

Comment: If you make the `MyClassVM` property `static`, (that is: `public static MyClass MyClassVM { .. }`) you should be able to access it from the controller like this: `WebApiApplication.MyClassVM`.